# jquery tabs avoiding anchor jumping from external link

Tags: jquery, url, tabs, anchor

I have a Jquery tabs on my page and I want to prevent that when the visitor comes to the page from an external link containing the anchor in the url (www.mypage.html#myanchor) the page will jump to the actual anchor. I just want the tab to be selected but not the jump.
I am still very novice in jquery, and this is the code I am using for building the tabs:

```
 <script>

    $(function() {

 $( "#tabs" ).tabs({

         select: function(event, ui) {

            // loading an iframe src on select
             if (ui.index==2){
             go('iframes/tendaggi_ignifughi.html');
             }
        }       

        });

});   

    </script>
```

Any answer on how should i modify the code above to achieve what I need is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code:

```
if (location.hash) {           // do the test straight away
    window.scrollTo(0, 0);     // execute it straight away
    setTimeout(function() {
        window.scrollTo(0, 0); // run it a bit later also for browser compatibility
    }, 1);
}
```